Angular binding fails inside structural directives on iphone?
As the title mentions, I'm having issues with data binding inside an ng-container with ngif specifically on iPhones (both Chrome and Safari).
Code example -
  <form>
  <input name="EmailInput" type="email" [(ngModel)]="Email"/>

  <ng-container *ngIf="ShowExtraInputs">
      <input name="PhoneInput" type="text" [(ngModel)]="Phone"/>
  </ng-container>

  </form>


In the example above, the boolean ShowExtraInputs starts as false and is adjusted to true after a few seconds, It works fine on desktop/android.
Specifically on Iphones, both on Safari and Chrome the phone input sometimes simply fails to bind, meaning everything seems to work fine, but the value of Phone property isn't bound to the input and its value stays empty.
Any tips on what might cause that?
Thanks

try `<div [hidden]="!ShowExtraInputs">
<input name="PhoneInput" type="text" [(ngModel)]="Phone"/>
` maybe the element getting destroyed was the problem?
Yeah using hidden works, but I'm still confused on why only on Iphones this issue occurs, it seems like the content inside the ngif which is added to the dom after the page loag simply doesn't bind .... odd

might be browser differences, but I guess it only happens for a particular scenario!

Due to browser differences you might be facing this problem, it does not happen often I guess, but you could try substituting [hidden] instead of *ngIf the differences between the two is that the hidden does not destroy the element! so that might fix your issue!
<div [hidden]="!ShowExtraInputs">       
    <input name="PhoneInput" type="text" [(ngModel)]="Phone"/>   
</div>

